# WPF ListView's height

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls, height

I have a `Grid` that contains `ListView`:

```
<Grid >
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition />
    ...
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <ListView Grid.Row="0">
   <ListViewItem >
    ...
   </ListViewItem>

   ...

 </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And `ListView` gets taller then all its items, it takes all available space.

How to make `ListView` exactly as tall as all the `ListViewItems` it contains (i.e. make it's height to be equal to sum of their heights)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should happen automatically if you don't set a `Height` or `MinHeight` property on your `ListView`.

**Edit:**
To resolve the situation where the ListView is taking up all available space, you can set the horizontal and vertical alignments. I have used the "Center" setting in my example, but "Left" or "Right" is also valid.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ListViewItem>Item 1</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item 2</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item 3</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Another possible solution is to set the SizeToContent on your window.

But be aware that if you have multiple parent containers wrapping your ListView, and you manually set the alignments or size properties on these containers, this solution may not work as expected.

You can take a look at this [link](http://www.wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html) to understand more about how layout works in xaml.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't. It takes all available place.

Comment: Ok I guess I understood your question to mean that the sum of ListViewItem heights was greater than the height of the ListView. If your situation is the opposite... i.e. the sum of ListViewItem heights is smaller than the ListView height. This is most likely because your ListView is automatically taking up all available space on the parent control(s). By default, if you don't specify a horizontal and vertical alignment, the ListView will try to take up all space (i.e. stretch). I will edit my answer to show you how to fix that.